# How to set up webproject using typescrip / webpack dev server and socket io

Tags: typescript, webpack, socket.io, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to set up a web project but I dont know if my choices are good.
I'm using Three.js, Socket.io and webpack.
(Then I plan to set up a Node server to interact with a future BDD but I would like to make the front working first)

First I created a scene with Three.js. As I want to use typeScript I chose webpack to build my files and serve them. (moreover it is very useful to reload on change etc .. )

When I open my browser at http://localhost:9000/ the scene appear. Now I would like to plug socket io to know when a client is connected. 
I know that I have to load the scrip in my index.html file `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

But ...
1 - Where should I put my server code ?? All my code in my main.ts is build and used front side... I read that webpack dev server use NodeJs to serve file. May I use it with socket IO ? I'm really confused at the moment :/

My project look like this :
`

```
|_app
|   |_scenes
|   |    |_myThreeJsScene.ts
|   |_main.ts
|_dist
|   |_index.html
|   |_main.js (builded with webpack)
|_package.json
|_tsconfig.json
|_webpack.config.js
```

`

My webpack config :

`

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './app/main.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 9000,
    https: true,
    open: 'chrome'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'main.js'
  }
};
```

`

2 - Also can you give advice about how should I organize my code ? (I dont know if 'app' is a a good name for my main folder etc .. :/ )

3 - Any other advice is really appreciated ! :D

Thx for your help !

Comment: Probably, you need to create 2 separate applications. The first one for the frontend app and the second one for the server. The server will just handle your requests (or socket events). The both of them can be built with webpack (two separate instances/configs) and run with two instances of webpack-dev-server. The client app you already have, so you need to create the server.

Comment: Indeed i have set up a quick nodeJs server and I could make the connection work ! I needed to add proxy conf in webpack to redirect the socket on the New nodeJs server. Thx ! :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help.